# биссектриса в sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Медиану и высоту в SymPy найти можно. А биссектрису ?

Мой текущий код:

```
from sympy import *
# нахождение медианы треуг-ка 
from sympy.geometry import * 
P1 = Point(0, 0) # Задаём 3 точки, три вершины треуг-ка 
P2 = Point(1, 1) # 
P3 = Point(1, 0) # 
# можно вставить проверку - образуют ли эти точки треугольник 
t = Triangle(P1, P2, P3) 
print(t.area) 
print(t.medians[P1]) 

# Результат: площадь -1/2 
# медиана Segment2D(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(1, 1/2))
```

Comment: Покажите как вы ищите медиану и высоту.

Comment: from sympy import *     # нахождение медианы треуг-ка
from sympy.geometry import *
P1 = Point(0, 0)        # Задаём 3 точки, три вершины треуг-ка
P2 = Point(1, 1)        #
P3 = Point(1, 0)        # 
# можно вставить проверку - образуют ли эти точки треугольник
t = Triangle(P1, P2, P3)
print(t.area)
print(t.medians[P1])     # Результат:  площадь     -1/2
                                     # медиана Segment2D(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(1, 1/2))

Comment: вы пробовали очевидное `t.bisectors[P1]` для биссектрисы по аналогии с `t.medians` для медианы?

Comment: Да, но видимо с ошибкой в синтаксисе. Теперь исправлено. Всё замечательно. Спасибо.